# How to check automatically that I didn't forget to add ef core code first migration

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We are using Entity Framework Core 2.2 with code first. Sometimes I change one of the entities, but forget to create a new migration, or I create a migration but only in one context (we have for different db engines). I want to check it automatically (ideally as NUnit test) so it runs in our CI server for every commit.

Manually I would try to create a new migration and check that created Up() and Down() methods are empty. It there any way to do it as a NUnit test?

Answer (score 1):

Where is difficulty in creating a test that :

1. Creates a new DB
2. Applies all current migrations to create a schema
3. Tries to use all the entities. It can be as simple as adding an entity, querying that entity and deep-comparing they are the same.
4. Drops the DB

If the schema doesn't have a migration for new entity or change in entity, you are sure to get and SQL error out of this.

Sure, every time you create a new entity, you would need to add a new test. But that should be already happening if you are using TDD.

And speed shouldn't be a problem either, as creating and dropping a DB shouldn't take more than few seconds and there won't be many of these kind of tests. And they can be parallelized.

If you want to get fancy and don't want to write test for each entity, it could be possible to do something like this :

1. Use reflection to get all entity types supported by a Context.
2. Use auto data generator like [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) or [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) to fill the entities with data.
3. Round-trip the entities through DB.
4. Compare the original with retrieved using deep-comparer like [Compare-Net-Objects](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects).

The usefulness of such automated approach would depend on complexity of your data model. Would just work for simple model. But would require lots of tweaking and overrides if the model is complex.